# What is the expiry time of the code parameter returned by google?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-calendar-api

I am integrating google calendar api, I have a url that is the redirect url after the application access is authenticated, the url returns a parameter code like

redirectUrl/code?='somecode'

i want to know the time expiry for the parameter code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The expiry of the access token is 3600 seconds only.
it could be revoked using refresh token or the access token it self, you may use the refresh token if the approval prompt for the google approval is kept "auto", but in the case you would get refresh token only once, using refresh token the response does not returns refresh token in this case but if you will use access token refresh token shall be generated with it, but if you use approval prompt of "force" type then you shall get the approval window every time.

Answer (score 1):

The default is 3600 seconds, or an hour. But if you make requests after that, the previous code will be invalid, but I'm sure you know that.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent#handlingtheresponse